# Iterating over Map of Maps

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map of maps. I want to iterate over each entry and get the value out of it. Following is my code I am using, but I get an exception. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry2 : ((Map<String, Object>)(Object) entry).entrySet()){
        sheet.addCell(new Label(c++, r+1, (String) entry2.getValue()));
    }

}
```

following is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$Node cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at com.vz.stamps.services.TestServiceForOrderPopup.addExcelOutputHeader(TestServiceForOrderPopup.java:97)
    at com.vz.stamps.services.TestServiceForOrderPopup.createExcelOutputExcel(TestServiceForOrderPopup.java:56)
    at com.vz.stamps.controller.OrderviewOpenDriverController.downloadExcelOutputExl(OrderviewOpenDriverController.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
```

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: can you post the entire exception message? lots of details/guidance here: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: sorry I had try catch on previously and I was not printing the stack trace, updated now

Comment: Is the value of first map is a map?

Comment: yes, each entry in the first map is a Map<String, Object>, I want to iterate over this entry

Comment: well, the stacktrace shows that instead of `java.util.Map`, you have an instance of `java.util.HashMap$Node`. it makes sense that it throws a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because after creating the `EntrySet` of first map and passing that for another iteration you are not calling `getValue()` on the `EntrySet`. So the code should be updated as:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry2 : ((Map<String, Object>)(Object) entry.getValue()).entrySet()){
        sheet.addCell(new Label(c++, r+1, (String) entry2.getValue()));
    }

}
```